# executing array_key_exists throws error

Tags: php, session

The following error i have received is

```
Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, 
null given in /home/*****/public_html/class/alerts.php on line 14
```

On line 14 in class/alerts.php i see the following line

```
if(!array_key_exists('flash_messages', $_SESSION)) $_SESSION['flash_messages'] = array();
```

I'm using the problem is inside $_SESSION but i'm not sure

Comment: Has the session been started by then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is suggesting that `$_SESSION` is null. This could be caused by not calling `session_start()` or perhaps the browser not accepting cookies.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's the problem i forgot to call session_start

Answer (score 0):

I would first check if $_SESSION is set and not empty before trying to index it.